# check mimetype of stored data using Python

Tags: python, mime-types

Problem: I extracted the content block from a WARC file. I am writing a filter to check the mimetype of this content block ***before*** saving the content into a file. Particularly, I am only interested in application/pdf types. The first few lines of the content look like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK^ML, 388610C
Date: Wed, 26 Jun 2013 02:18:37 GMT^M
Server: Apache^M
Last-Modified: Thu, 02 Dec 2010 22:54:07 GMT^M
ETag: "9002f-41fc8-4c94c1c0"^M
Accept-Ranges: bytes^M
Content-Length: 270280^M
Connection: close^M
Content-Type: application/pdf^M
^M
%PDF-1.4
%ÐÔÅØ
1 0 obj
<< /S /GoTo /D [2 0 R  /Fit ] >>
endobj
7 0 obj <<
/Length 297
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
```

Attempted approaches:
I've tried the following approaches and they all failed (assuming `content` variable contains the block above):
(1) StringIO+mimetypes

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import mimetypes
iocontent = StringIO(content)
print mimetypes.guess_type(iocontent)

it just prints (None,None).
```

(2) magic package

```
import magic
print magic.from_buffer(content)

it prints `ASCII text, with CRLF, LF line terminators`.
```

(3) subprocess.Popen()

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE,STDOUT

p = Popen('file --mime-type', stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
cmd_out = p.communicate(input=content)[0]
```

The output is an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "warc_extract_pdf.py", line 123, in <module>
    run()
  File "warc_extract_pdf.py", line 102, in run
    sys.exit(main(argvs))
  File "warc_extract_pdf.py", line 35, in main
    if extract_pdf(offset,record,outdir,outlog): 
  File "warc_extract_pdf.py", line 61, in extract_pdf
    if not mimetype(record,'application/pdf'): return False
  File "warc_extract_pdf.py", line 75, in mimetype
    p = Popen('file --mime-type', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Pleas help!

Comment: What is content? The path to a file? Pleas post its declaration.

Comment: Popen expects a sequence, like: `['file', '--mime-type']`

Comment: As I posted, the "content" variable contains a string starting with "HTTP/1.1 200".

Comment: Changing the 'file --mime-type' to ['file','--mime-type'] does not help. It generated error messages, saying that I did not use the "file" command correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[warc](http://warc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is a python library for parsing WARC files and getting information from them. This file is just text until you parse it as a http request. From their examples, your use case would look something like this:

```
import warc
f = warc.open("test.warc")
for record in f:
    print record.get("Content-Type","text/html")
```

Comment: That's correct. However, these WARC files are generated by a web crawler called Heritrix. The Content-Types are not well recorded by Heritrix. Most values are just "application/http; msgtype=request", which are useless. That is why I have to check the mime-type myself. In addition, I do not think the warc package can retrieve the content for me.

Comment: Ok, then it is beyond my depth. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but figured I could answer anyway.

Python-Magic will work here. Just have to use .from_buffer(buffer, **mime=True**)

```
import magic
import StringIO
msg_part_io_str = StringIO.StringIO()
with open('./Downloads/test123123.pdf', 'r') as f:
    msg_part_io_str.write(f.read())

d = magic.from_buffer(msg_part_io_str.getvalue(), mime=True)

print d
application/pdf
```

https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic#usage